# Как сгруппировать данные по 14 дней в PostreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Имеется следующая таблица:

|  | session_date_time | mentor_cnt | mentee_cnt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-02-12 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2021-02-17 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-02-19 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2021-03-06 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 2021-03-27 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 2021-03-31 | 1 | 1 |
| 6 | 2021-04-10 | 1 | 1 |
| 7 | 2021-04-12 | 1 | 1 |
| 8 | 2021-04-15 | 2 | 2 |
| 9 | 2021-04-18 | 1 | 1 |
| 10 | 2021-04-19 | 1 | 1 |
| 11 | 2021-04-22 | 1 | 1 |
| 12 | 2021-05-01 | 1 | 1 |
| 13 | 2021-05-02 | 1 | 1 |
| 14 | 2021-05-07 | 1 | 1 |

Как сгруппировать данные по 14 дней независимо от начала недели?
Интервал в 14 дней нужно считать от последней даты.

Желаемый результат:

|  | session_date_time | mentor_cnt | mentee_cnt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2021-02-05 00:00:00 | 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 2021-02-20 00:00:00 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 2021-03-17 00:00:00 | 2 | 2 |
| 11 | 2021-04-08 00:00:00 | 7 | 7 |
| 14 | 2021-04-23 00:00:00 | 3 | 3 |

Comment: Результат добавил, по сути мне нужно с последней даты выделить интервалы по 14 дней и использовать их для группировки.

Comment: А что мешает посчитать разницу между последней да текущей датами в днях и поделить её целочисельно на 14?

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку. Как ни странно, я пробовал решить проблему с делением на 14, но немного накосячил.